# MapServer symbol repeating

Tags: mapserver

I am trying to create a symbol in MapServer. In this occasion it's a cross over a church. So I found a .png image of a black cross and include it in my symbolset.sym file:

```
SYMBOLSET
  SYMBOL
    NAME 'cross'
    TYPE PIXMAP
    IMAGE "cross.png"            
  END
END
```

and in my mapfile:

```
 CLASS                 
  NAME "Church"
  EXPRESSION (("[building]" IN "church,chapel"))                   
  STYLE
      COLOR 208 202 208        
      MAXSCALEDENOM 8000
  END   
  STYLE
      SYMBOL "cross" 
      SIZE 100
  END                  
END
```

The effects produced are weird though. My layer includes `SIZEUNITS meters` so the more I zoom in, the smaller the symbol get. And apart from that the symbol is repeated inside my polygon. 
[image: chapel_with_cross]

How can I maintain the size of the symbol and stop the repeating effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is how MapServer is using symbols with polygons - it creates a polygon fill. See examples from http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/symbology/construction.html

For getting a single symbol for a church you have two options:

1. Create a different point layer that contains the centroids or whatever you want to use as symbol points
2. Use GEOMTRANSFORM http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/geomtransform.html in your STYLE block.

For the latter I would try

```
 STYLE
    GEOMTRANSFORM "centroid"      
    SYMBOL "cross" 
    SIZE 100
 END
```

That should work well for buildings but I am not sure about the result if the polygon in large and if client is making 256x256 tiled requests.

Comment: huh... second option worked well. Thank you I tried it before but I was using "bbox" instead of centroid. I can't be sure about the tiles. I am planning to use mapcache. I'll be back as soon as I set it up